# How to efficiently use CompletableFuture to map async task per input

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, guava, completable-future

I want to return map consisting mapping of all keys to value being API response to those keys. I am using `CompletableFuture` and `Guava` for this. Below is my attempt. Is there any other standard way to achieve the same with Java 8 and threading APIs?

Map being `id -> apiResponse(id)`.

```
    
    public static List<String> returnAPIResponse(Integer key) {
        return Lists.newArrayList(key.toString() + " Test");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> keys = Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4);

        List<CompletableFuture<SimpleEntry<Integer, List<String>>>> futures = keys
            .stream()
            .map(key -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                () -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(key, returnAPIResponse(key))))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(
            futures.parallelStream()
            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));

    }
```

Comment: hmm, what is your question? if you want a `Map`, just replace `collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)))`

Comment: My question is if the code I presented, is this the way to do things ? In the end I want to get API response for every datakey I passed in the map asynchronously. 

Map being id -> apiResponse(id).

Comment: you will still need to eventually block somewhere to get the result, like you do with `join`, you understand that, right?

Comment: Yes that part is okay but actual use and construction of `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` I was little apprehensive about. This code does the job but I wanted to know if there is any other better way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an interesting behavior here that I will try my best to explain. Let's start simple, let's forget about `CompletableFuture` for a second and simply do this with a plain `parallelStream`, with a minor debugging step added:

```
List<Integer> keys = Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16);

Map<Integer, List<String>> result =
    keys.parallelStream()
        .map(x -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(x, returnAPIResponse(x)))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

System.out.println("parallelism : " + pool.getParallelism() + " current : " + pool.getPoolSize());
```

On my machine, this prints:

```
parallelism : 11 current : 11
```

I assume you already know that actions of `parallelStream` are executes in the `common` `ForkJoinPool`. It is probably also obvious what that output means: `11 threads` were available and all of them were used.

I'll slightly modify your example now:

```
List<Integer> keys = Lists.newArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16);

ForkJoinPool pool = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();
ExecutorService supplyPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

Map<Integer, List<String>> result =
keys.parallelStream()
    .map(x -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
             () -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(x, returnAPIResponse(x)),
             supplyPool
    ))
    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

 System.out.println("parallelism : " + pool.getParallelism() + " current : " + pool.getPoolSize());
```

It's actually just one important change, I'll let your `supplyAsync` run in its own thread pool; the rest is the same. Running this, reveals:

```
parallelism : 11 current : 16
```

Surprise. More threads were created then what we wanted? Well, the documentation of `getPoolSize` says that:

> Returns the number of worker threads that have started but not yet terminated.  The result returned by this method may differ from getParallelism when threads are created to maintain parallelism when others are **cooperatively blocked**.

The blocking in your case happens via `map(CompletableFuture::join)`. You have effectively blocked a worker thread from `ForkJoinPool` and it compensates that by spinning another one.

---

If you do not want to get into such a surprise:

```
List<CompletableFuture<AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<Integer, List<String>>>> list =
keys.stream()
    .map(x -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
         () -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(x, returnAPIResponse(x)),
         supplyPool
     ))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

CompletableFuture.allOf(list.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();

Map<Integer, List<String>> result =
list.stream()
    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Because there is no `join` on the worker threads of `ForJoinPool`, you can drop `parallelStream`. Then I still *block* to get the result via:

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(list.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();
```

but there will be no compensating threads generated. And because `CompletableFuture.allOf` returns a `CompletableFuture<Void>`, I need to stream again to get the results.

Don't let that `.map(CompletableFuture::join)` in the last stream operation fool you, there is no blocking because of the previous `CompletableFuture::allOf`, which already blocked and waited for all tasks to finish.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful post ! Got some insight on the topic.